# ASP.NET Web Api and UrlDecode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, urldecode, asp.net-web-api

Is this a bug in the framework?

I have to use HttpUtility.UrlDecode here. I thought things were automatically decoded in MVC.

```cs
    public Thingy[] Get(string id)
    {
        var actualId = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(id ?? string.Empty);

        var result = MakeThingy(actualId );
        return result;
    }
```

I should be able to just do this ...

```cs
    public Thingy[] Get(string id)
    {
        var result = MakeThingy(id ?? string.Empty);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a known bug. We'll fix it for the next release.

Comment: please excuse my ignorance, but are you the PM for ASP.NET-Web-Api? I've noticed you've answered a few of my related question in a very authoritative manner :)

Comment: Not the PM, but one of the developers (on both MVC and Web API). I try to make it clear in my SO profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/358970/marcind